# Java `sgn` function in Comparable API doc

Tags: java

I read

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) ==
>   -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y.

on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html. It seems to me `sgn` is not a Java function - am I right? If `sgn` denotes sign, can't one just say `x.compareTo(y) == -y.compareTo(x)`? I know this question may be fastidious, but I want this to be clear.

Comment: They probably meant `Math.signum()`, which returns -1, 0, or 1 as applicable to the argument.

Comment: If you continue reading the documentation they clearly defined what they mean when they say `sgn`. "_In the foregoing description, the notation sgn(expression) designates the mathematical signum function, which is defined to ..._".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Further down in the [same Javadocs for `compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-), the "sgn" function is described.

> In the foregoing description, the notation *sgn(expression)* designates the mathematical sign function, which is defined to return one of `-1`, `0`, or `1` according to whether the value of *expression* is negative, zero, or positive, respectively.

There is no `sgn` method that I can see in Java.  However, there is a [`Math.signum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum-double-) method that returns the sign of `double` or `float`.

The writers could have said

> ```
> Math.signum(x.compareTo(y)) == Math.signum(-y.compareTo(x))
> ```

but referring to the [well-known mathematical function ("sgn")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) was sufficient.

Specifying that `x.compareTo(y) == -y.compareTo(x)` is unnecessarily restrictive.  The contract of `compareTo` only states

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than

For less than, it doesn't matter whether it returns -1, -3, -5, or -1000000.  It's perfectly fine for `a.compareTo(b)` to return `-1` and `b.compareTo(a)` to return `3`.  The result when switching the variables doesn't have to be the mathematical opposite value.

Comment: Ah this made it clear for me. Somehow I assumed the sign function had a left inverse (wrt function composition), but that's clearly not the case.